# Connect two mikrotik LAN

Tags: router, wifi, mikrotik, wireless-bridge

I got two RB951G-2HnD and two RBSXTG-5HPnD-HGr2.

> (clientsOfLan1) ))> RB1 <---> SXT1 ))> <(( SXT2 <---> RB2 <((
>   (clientsOfLan2)

I need to 'connect' two LAN's around 951.

I can't figure out how to 'bridge' those two networks that clientsOfLan1 could see clientsOfLan2 on L2 layer.

RB1/2 is in `ap bridge`
SXT1 is `station pseudobridge`
SXT2 is `ap bridge`

I am quite lost. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? I need same L2 (ethernet) network on both sides best possible latency and bandwidth. I want use/setup SXT1 and SXT2 to simulate a 'wire' that I connect between those two routerboards.

Comment: Are LAN1 and LAN2 on the same subnet?

Comment: They are both on 10.0.0.0/24 (L3). But I dont know to setup SXT's to create 'switching' (L2) network.

Comment: Don't bridge two IP networks through a pseudobridge. Pseudobriding is only suitable for bridging a single layer 2 device.

Answer (score 1):

(clientsOfLan1) ))> RB1 <---> SXT1 ))> <(( SXT2 <---> switch <(( (clientsOfLan2)

if you want LAN1 and LAN2 use the same subnet, just make RB1 as the main router.
LAN1 and LAN2 assign DHCP from RB1.

i did it on my office.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use WDS mode= dynamic on SXT routers, wds-bridge=bridge1 and to create bridge1 between eth and wlan interfaces on those SXT int. Set up mode of SXT1 to AP bridge and to SXT2 to Station-Wds.
This link will be the same as you connect ethernet cable between the two RB951. 
Even the ip addresses you will give to those SXT devices does not have to be on the same network as the net of the two RB951.